# How to map lists of values to categorical vector

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do some clustering on a dataset of videos based on duration. I have a dictionary in which keys are user IDs, and values are a list of float (videos duration), 1 float per video created by the user.

Example :

```
videos_per_user = {
    63: [15.011667, 21.823333, 29.981667, 10.341667, 14.928333, 16.555, 29.976667], 
    64: [5.463333, 14.345, 5.571667, 18.848333]
}
```

Important note : these lists are not of the same length.

What I'm trying to do is to transform this dict to a pandas Dataframe, based on a reference vector (bins) so I can have a vector for each user that contains the number of videos for each category.

I've created my categorical vector as follows :
`bins = pd.Series(np.arange(start=0,stop=35,step=5))`

I've tried to use `pd.cut(videos_per_user, bins=bins, right=True)` but I get the corresponding category for each duration while I'm trying to get something like : `[0,0,2,2,3,0]`

Any ideas ? I didn't find similar situations on the web, but maybe because I don't really knowhow to correctly formulate my problem.

To conclude, I'd like to create a vector of length 6 (6 categories) for each user in my dict with the number of videos with the corresponding duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `searchsorted` and `bincount`

```
b = np.arange(5, 30, 5)
# array([ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** The `minlength` is what guarantees that all arrays will be of the same length.  However, it needs to be set at the actual number of categories you expect to have.  This can change if your actual set up isn't exactly as described in the question.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    user: np.bincount(b.searchsorted(durations), minlength=len(b) + 1)
    for user, durations in videos_per_user.items()
})

   63  64
0   0   0
1   0   2
2   2   1
3   2   1
4   1   0
5   2   0
```

---

#### `value_counts` and `cut`

```
pd.DataFrame({
    user: pd.value_counts(pd.cut(durations, bins))
    for user, durations in videos_per_user.items()
})

          63  64
(0, 5]     0   0
(5, 10]    0   2
(10, 15]   2   1
(15, 20]   2   1
(20, 25]   1   0
(25, 30]   2   0
```

Comment: I get the following exception : `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: Yes, but I've tested your solution too because it seemed to do what I wanted

Comment: Which one did you test?  Did they both result in the same error?

Comment: Oh, you're right, the one with `searchsorted` and `bincount` gave me the error above. Your solution with `value_counts` and `cut` works well.

Comment: Did you specify the `minlength=6`?

Comment: Yes I did. And I do need 6 categories in output in my actual setup

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing you want to do is to overcome the difference sizes of the dict. The only way I can think of is to use dict comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k,a) for k,v in videos_per_user.items() 
                         for a in v], 
                  columns=('user', 'val'))

# cut by bins
df['cat'] = pd.cut(df.val, bins=bins)

# pivot to get the data
df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='cat', aggfunc='count')
```

Output:

```
         val                                    
cat  (5, 10] (10, 15] (15, 20] (20, 25] (25, 30]
user                                            
63       NaN      2.0      2.0      1.0      2.0
64       2.0      1.0      1.0      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to do ! I added `fill_value = 0` when creating the pivot_table btw

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.cut()` you can do the following:

`pd.cut(videos_per_user, 6)`